# Does the Twitter iOS API provide any way of determining if the tweet was successful?

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

I'm using the following snippet of code to make a tweet in my iOS 5 application :

```
- (IBAction)postToTwitterClicked:(id)sender 
{
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]init];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Some sample message here"];
        [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL"]];

        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unable to tweet"
                                                     message:@"Please ensure that you have at least one twitter account setup and have internet connectivity. You can setup a twitter account in the iOS Settings > Twitter > login."
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av show]; 
    }
}
```

This works fine, but how do I know that the user did actually post a tweet, or if there was a problem?

Since this doesn't implement a delegate, there are no "onError" methods that I can override.

I want to know if the user did successfully post a tweet, so I can action some behaviour such as

1. Disable a button so they can't do it again
2. Notify them the post was successful and will show up in their feed shortly

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in the iOS Twitter API that you can see that a Tweet actually was posted on the server. But you can analyze the `TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult` to see if the tweet was finished composing successfully or if the tweet was cancelled.

```
twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res) {
    if (res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
         // Composed
    } else if (res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
        // Cancelled
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, you only can set a handler to call when the user is done composing the tweet: `TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler`. This [handler](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) has a single parameter that indicates whether the user finished or cancelled composing the tweet.

You can try to send a tweet and make it fail to check the result code (luckily it's cancelled?).

Another alternative to achieve the desired behaviour is use another API.